# XSLT replace value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMDefault xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintDollarsAndCents>X</PrintDollarsAndCents>
   <MailAddrLine1>Add1</MailAddrLine1>
   <MailAddrLine2>Add2</MailAddrLine2>
</OMDefault>
```

I would like to have an XSLT to transform the XML to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMDefault xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintDollarsAndCents>Y</PrintDollarsAndCents>
   <MailAddrLine1>Add1</MailAddrLine1>
   <MailAddrLine2>Add2</MailAddrLine2>
 </OMDefault>
```

Please notice the 'X' gets transformed to 'Y' if the attribute is PrintDollarsAndCents and its value is 'X'
Could someone please help me with this? As I am very new to this XSLT thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your output looks identical to your input and I do not understand your "please notice" sentence.  Could you please show what you want to see as an output when your special case is detected in the input?  How would you write the special case detection in pseudo code?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, it should be like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMDefault xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintDollarsAndCents>Y</PrintDollarsAndCents>
   <MailAddrLine1>Add1</MailAddrLine1>
   <MailAddrLine2>Add2</MailAddrLine2>
 </OMDefault>

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Basically you want an identity transform, with override rules.

The following transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PrintDollarsAndCents/text()[.='X']">Y</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input, produces the result:

```
<OMDefault xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintDollarsAndCents>Y</PrintDollarsAndCents>
   <MailAddrLine1>Add1</MailAddrLine1>
   <MailAddrLine2>Add2</MailAddrLine2>
</OMDefault>
```

The first template is an identity transform, which copies the input document exactly.

The second template overrides text nodes with a value of `X` that are children of a `PrintDollarsAndCents` template.  Note that it emits the value `Y` instead of its actual content.

Comment: If I have something like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMDefault xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintDollarsAndCents>X</PrintDollarsAndCents>
   <MailAddrLine2>Add2</MailAddrLine2>
</OMDefault>

I would like to have an XSLT to transform the XML to this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMDefault xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <PrintDollarsAndCents>Y</PrintDollarsAndCents>
   <MailAddrLine1>Add1</MailAddrLine1>
   <MailAddrLine2>Add2</MailAddrLine2>
 </OMDefault>

Comment: @DuyTran, please update your question or ask a new one.  It is difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: Harpo, there is a limit I can't post all of it. Please go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734294/xslt-match-and-replace  Thanks

Comment: I think your identity transform needs one small addition. I found that it didn't preserve Unicode encoding. Adding the following made it work for me: <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" />