# How to replace data of an xml element with another value in mule?

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

How to replace data of an xml element with another value in mule?
For eg

```
<users>
<user>
    <name>abc</name>
    <city>qwe</city>
    <countryCode>india</countryCode>
</user>
<user>
    <name>yiu</name>
    <city>cdc</city>
    <countryCode>france</countryCode>
</user>
<user>
    <name>wddq</name>
    <city>dqdqw</city>
    <countryCode>brazil</countryCode>
</user>
```

I want to replace the `countryCode` VALUES to pre-defined values, LIKE I want to have IN for india , BA for brazil ,FC for france.

What should be the best way to do it in mule. For now I am trying to use this values from a properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this simply using a property files were I could put my which predefined definitions having a list of country-> country-code mapping following is a dataweave code snippet.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    countryCodeReplacements : p(payload.users.*user.countryCode)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think here you have 2 options:

1. If you need to perform other changes to the XML, then I would suggest a transformation with DataWeave (or DataMapper if you use an older version of Mule).
2. If instead you really need just to replace those values, then I think the logical approach would be an XSLT transformation.

You can do the XSLT transformation by using the [XSLT transformer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xslt-transformer) but you will need to write your own transformation XML, there is no graphical aid, but isn't that difficult.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560446/xslt-replace-value) should give you some hint about replacing value in XSLT.